# wss connection to node ws server via nginx, ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a websocket server running behind nginx.

Connecting via http works ok (ws://mywebsite.com) with following nginx config:

```
http {

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    
    location /myWebSocket {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
    }

}
```

I'd like to connect to this via https (wss://mywebsite.com) and have tried this:

```
http {
      server {
            listen       443 ssl http2 ;
            listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 ;
            server_name mywebsite.com; # managed by Certbot
            root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
            ssl_certificate /etc/mycert.pem; 
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/mykey.pem; 
            ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
            ssl_session_timeout  10m;
            ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
            
            location /myWebSocket {
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            }
      }
}
```

However, I get a `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` on the browser side (e.g. with `wss://myWebsite/myWebSocket`).

My understanding is that WSS is a connection to a standard websocket via https, is this correct?

Is my approach above correct?

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

To confirm the cert was installed with certbot, and the e.g. https://example.com works.

Note also, there is another server block listening on 443, this does not define the /myWebSocket location (I think it is the nginx default ssl block that is superceded by certbot block).

Edit: note removing that first ssl server block results in the browser side websocket connection error message changing to `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

Another Edit: I was connecting using the server's IP address not the DNS name - that removed the error. :-)

Comment: Is your TLS cert (from certbot / LetsEncrypt) installed correctly? What do you get if you hit the non-websocket part of that server with a web browser? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @O.Jones yes, non-websocket part works. Have updated questions, thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is somehow related to the fact your server now has an HTTP/2 support? Try adding `proxy_http_version 1.1;` to the websocket handler location.

Comment: @IvanShatsky thanks, but that didn't work